# Firefox won't play mp4 natively, it seems to skip to the end

Tags: windows, firefox, mp4

I am having issues with Firefox 24 playing my `mp4` videos. I enter the url to the video in the address bar (e.g. `http://www.mywebsite.com/video.mp4`) the video appears to load and skips to the end and shows the "repeat" icon. If I click the icon the video attempts to load and skips to the end again.

In Firebug I can see three requests

1. The first request asks for the whole video and returns a `200 OK`.
2. The second request asks for the very end of the video (`Range : bytes=33390592-`) and gets a `206 Partial Content` for the requested range (`Content-Range : bytes 33390592-33860228/33860229`)
3. The third request asks for a substantial part of the video (`Range : bytes=65536-`) and again gets a `206 Partial Content` reponse for the requested range (`Content-Range : bytes 65536-33860228/33860229`)

In Chrome I see only the first request/response and the video plays correctly.

The `Content-Type` of the video is `video/mp4` in all three requests.

Any ideas?

Comment: Firefox relies on OS components to play MP4, and only supports it on some platforms.  Due to patent issues it cannot be built-in like the free formats.  Since it is platform-specific you should tag the question with the platform you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my issue was down to my computers video drivers being out of date (they were over 3 years old). Running windows update fixed my issue.

Comment: Doesn't that make the question off topic here and on topic on [SU]?

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek I guess you're right. I've voted to close too.